# How to clear a textbox once a button is clicked in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, textbox

How can I clear a `textbox` once a button is clicked in the WPF application, I know I have to do it in click method of the button but what code should I use for the mentioned purpose?

Comment: textBoxName.Text = String.Empty;

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Give your textbox a name and then use `TextBoxName.Text = String.Empty;`

Comment: This one is the good solution if you want to avoid `DataBindings` on WPF.

Answer (score 14):

I use this. I think this is the simpliest way to do it:

```
 textBoxName.Clear();
```

Answer (score 6):

For example:

XAML:

```
<Button Content="ok" Click="Button_Click"/>
<TextBlock Name="textBoxName"/>
```

In code:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
textBoxName.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Any** of the statement given below to clear the text of the text box on button click:

1. `textBoxName.Text = string.Empty;`
2. `textBoxName.Clear();`
3. `textBoxName.Text = "";`

Answer (score 6):

There is one possible pitfall with using `textBoxName.Text = string.Empty;` and that is if you are using Text binding for your TextBox (i.e. `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}"></TextBox>`). In this case, setting an empty string will actually override and break your binding.

To prevent this behavior you have to use the Clear method:

```
textBoxName.Clear();
```

This way the TextBox will be cleared, but the binding will be kept intact.

Comment: If you’re using bindings properly, it might make more sense to set the *viewmodel* property to the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't have to put it in the button click hander. If you were, then you'd assign your text box a name (`x:Name`) in your view and then use the generated member of the same name in the code behind to set the `Text` property.

If you were avoiding code behind, then you would investigate the MVVM design pattern and data binding, and bind a property on your view model to the text box's `Text` property.

Comment: Intriguing - will investigate, as soon as I've finished the "native WPF" tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

For me `texBoxName.Clear()`;is the best method because I have textboxs in binding and if I use other methods I do not have a good day

Answer (score 0):

When you run your form and you want showing text in textbox is clear so you put the code : -

```
textBox1.text = String.Empty;
```

Where textBox1 is your textbox name.

Comment: What is the added value considering the accepted answer?